# jQuery find only not nested elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given this HTML structure

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item">
        select me
        <div class="item">don't select me</div>
    </div>
    <span>
        <div class="item">select me</div>
    </span>
</div>
```

And this jQuery:

```
var firstItem = $('.item:first');
var selector = firstItem.find('.item');
selector.css('color', 'red');
```

I am looking for a way to mark only the not nested .item elements inside the firstItem div. The tricky part here is that the firstItem itself is (or can be) already nested in .item class.

---

What have I tried?

```
firstItem.find('.item').not('.item .item')
```

This does not work because the first level we are starting in is already an .item class. And that can be nested x times already so it could be .item .item .item .item or whatever. And the starting element does not have an ID so I cannot use that in the selector as well.

---

I think the solution should be something like a reversed [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) which travels down the DOM and does not search the contents of an already found item.

Prepared a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LWmy3/2/

Comment: Maaaaybe this? [.parentsUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/)

Comment: How would you use .parentsUntil in this case?

Comment: c'mon yaar cant you add sepeate classes for accebility

Comment: @CoolGadgetsForGeeks I've added a demo with the `parentsUntil()`, which would need an extra class though :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var firstItem = $('.item:first');
$(firstItem).find(".item").each(function () {
    //console.log($(this).parent(".item")[0])
    if ($(this).parent(".item")[0] === undefined) {
        $(this).css('color', 'red')
    } else if ($(this).parent(".item")[0] != $(firstItem)[0]) {
        $(this).css('color', 'cyan')
    } else {
        $(this).css('color', 'red')
    }
});
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/LWmy3/4/)

Comment: I think if "don't select me" is wrapped by a div it will not work.

Comment: @melc - if it is not wrapped by div, it would belong to the parent, is it not

Comment: wrapperd or not it would still be a nested .item with the same .item parent, if i understood the query correctly

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LWmy3/73/ added <div class="item">don't select me</div> within a div.

Answer (score 0):

What about selecting the first nested `.item` and its siblings?

I've updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LWmy3/3/ using a red border instead of red text to show that it's not selecting the "don't select me" item.

Edit: using each()

http://jsfiddle.net/LWmy3/5/

Comment: Thank you Karine but this does not work if the DOM structure is different (like other divs around the items).

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the second fiddle with the span! In this case, I can only think of using each() on the selector... http://jsfiddle.net/LWmy3/5/

Answer (score 0):

This also works,

```
var firstItem = $('.item').eq(0);
var selector = firstItem.find('.item').each(function(){
    var $parents = $(this).parents('.item');
    if($parents.eq(0)[0]==firstItem[0]){
       $(this).css('color', 'red');     
    }else{
        $(this).css('color', 'blue');     
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LWmy3/10/
However if the firstItem is nested itselft then you'll have to modify the first line and instead of calling

```
 $('.item').eq(0)
```

you should modify 0 with the level of nesting i.e.

```
 $('.item').eq(1)//if it has one .item parent
```

Answer (score 0):

### With $(selector)

```
$('.item:not(.item:first-child .item .item)').css( 'color', 'purple' );
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/yTVPr/22/

---

### With .each()

```
$(".item:first-child").each(function( index, element ) {
    if ( $(this).parents( '.item' ).length <= 1 )
        $(this).css( 'color', 'red' );
    else
        $(this).css( 'color', 'black' );
});
```

Added extra DOM elements for testing, although I think most people came up with the same idea. I think it's rather hard without putting at least a single ID or class to indicate a nest.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/yTVPr/

---

### With Root Element & parentsUntil()

If you did include a class for a nested 'level', you could transverse the each() and find the length matching aganist `parentsUntil()` like below:

```
<div class="item toplevel">
    <div class="item">
        select me
        <div class="item">don't select me</div>
    </div>
    <span>
        <div class="item">select me</div>
    </span>
</div>

<script>
   /** 
    *  Transverse Up the tree
    *  to find .toplevel, if length
    *  0, then it's met the parent/target. 
   **/
   $(".item").each(function( index, element ) {
       if ( $(this).parentsUntil( '.toplevel', '.item' ).length === 0 )
           $(this).css( 'color', 'blue' );
   });
</script>
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/yTVPr/19/

Answer (score 0):

You can select all matching elements with `find()` and then remove all nested elements matching the selector. For easier usage this can be wrapped in a jQuery extension function:

```
$.fn.flatFind = function(selector) {
   // Find everything matching the selector
   var all = this.find(selector);
   // Find nodes nested into one of the "direct" matches
   var nested = all.find(selector);
   // Return everything but the nested nodes
   return all.not(nested);
}
```

This function would then [be used like this](http://jsfiddle.net/L3dp1ynf/):

```
var baseItem = $(".item:first")
baseItem.flatFind('.item').css('color', 'red');
```